# Spring data jpa - autowiring of repository does not work

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data with JPA. I use to XML files:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.aa.bb" />
<bean id="exceptionPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:bb.properties"/>

<!-- DATA BASE -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="spiedDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aa.bb.cc.domain" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="database" value="SQL_SERVER" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClass}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.pwd}" />
</bean>

<bean id="spiedDataSource" class="com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6DataSource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref local="dataSource"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="spiedDataSource" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.aa.bb.cc.repository" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

And another beans xml for quartz timing :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="dailyMailJob" class="com.aa.bb.cc.timer.DailyMailJob">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender" class="com.aa.bb.cc.util.MailSender">
    <!-- <property name="mailsList" value="${bb.properties.mail.list}"/> -->
</bean>

<bean id="runMeJob"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="dailyMailJob" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="sendDailyMail" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="5 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="runMeJob" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, I try to autowire a Repository interface to a class declared on the second XML file:

```
public class DailyMailJob {

@Autowired
private MessageNotifyRepository messageNotifyRepository;

private MailSender mailSender;
...
```

I get NULL on the messageNotifyRepository field.

How can I fix this? It seems like wrong configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution.

It was quite simple and basic spring issue, and I probably missed it because I got messed up with repositories.

All I had to do is add `<import resource="XML2" />` on the first XML file.

Thanks anyway...

Ido

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a piece of configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <repositories base-package="com.aa.bb.???" />

</beans:beans>
```

In which `???` should be the package to look for Data JPA repositories. Refer to [the reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.spring) for more details.

Comment: At the first xml file there is:
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.aa.bb.cc.repository" /> and if I add it on the second XML file it tries to autowire entity manager and fails to find one.

Comment: I missed that one, sorry. But, then it seems that `DailyMailJob` misses an annotation like `@Service`, or is it not included in the example code here?

Comment: It is declared on the second XML with <bean> tag so it does not need to be annotated ad a Service or a Component. Thanks but I think this is a problem with the combination of these two XML files.